# Why can't "could" be used with action verbs in the past tense?

Tags: difference, auxiliary-verbs

> But you should only use ‘was/were able to’ with action verbs to talk about an ability related to a single event or incident in the past.
>
> Examples:
>   I was able to surprise my teacher yesterday.
>   Don’t say: I could surprise my teacher yesterday.

This is an excerpt from a site. (https://blogs.transparent.com/english/cancould-vs-to-be-able-to/)

I can't understand what that means.

Why can't "could" be used with action verbs in the past tense?

Comment: Read the post more carefully; it says *could* is not used for the ability related to *a single event or incident in the past*. You can certainly say *I could have surprised my teacher yesterday*, for example, which describes your general state yesterday rather than a single moment.

Comment: @choster Ah... now I understand what you were saying.